# Hibernate uses update when I try to insert new records

Tags: spring, hibernate

[image]

I have a database structure as above. then I was trying to insert a new record with post in below format

```
{
    "userId": 2,
    "firstName": "project",
    "lastName": "principa;",
    "username": "principal1",
    "password": "$2a$04$eFytJDGtjbThXa80FyOOBuFdK2IwjyWefYkMpiBEFlpBwDH.5PM0K",
    "institution": {
        "institutionID": 3,
        "institutionName": "new_test_schoo;"
    },
    "authorities": [
        {
            "authorityID": 2,
            "authority": "principal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then from the console and table, I can see the institution is inserted, but hibernate was trying to do update.

```
Hibernate: insert into users (first_name, institution_id, last_name, password, username) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update authorities set authority=?, user_id=? where authority_id=?
```

I was using following method to insert new a new record

```
@Override
public void saveUser(Users theUser) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.save(theUser);
}
```

And here is my entity class of Users

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="user_id")
private int userId;
@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name="username")
private String username;
@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="institution_id")
private Institution institution;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy="user", 
            cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Authorities> authorities;
...setters and getters
```

It is clear that

```
  "authorities": [
        {
            "authorityID": 2,
            "authority": "principal"
        }
    ]
```

doest not exist in authorities table, but why hibernate was trying to use update instead of insert? And how can I solve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

=======================Update================================

There is a quick update, I solved this issue by change `CascadeType` to `CascadeType.ALL`. But I do not feel it is right. As if I want to delete one sigle user, the institution will be deleted as well. Am I right? But I have tried remove `@GeneratedValue` and `@Id`. It only throws me error. And I do not think `@GeneratedValue` will effect the result. As if I assign the Id, the database will store this particulate it. However, if I do not assign the Id, the database will generated it automatically.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a potential fix.

I redefined Users class in this below

I try to separate the inserting steps, and it works fine now.
And everything works fine now. Thx for all the help you provided.

Answer (score 0):

When cascading on hibernate, if the cascaded entity has a primary key which is already persisted  hibernate will not persist a new entity.

For the update I assume your relation is bidirectional so hibernate needs to update the authorities when adding a new user.

Comment: Hi thx for your reply. OneToMany in users class and ManyToOne in authorities class. OneToMany is mappedby the users, and in authorities table I use JoinColumn(user_id) which is primary key in users table but foreign key in authorities table. So in this case, hibernate will not try to create a new entity? If so how can i ask to create a new one? Remove CascadeType.PERSIST from both users and authorities class?

Comment: to ask hibernate to cascade a new object your object should not contain the id or remove generatedValue annotation from your model

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using the annotation @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference in some cases (cyclic reference).

Try replacing with JsonIgnore and running the saveAuthorities method manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set id while inserting to Authority, you must remove `@GeneratedValue` from Authority entity.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to see, as if I provide the ID, then the Hibernate will think this already exits. But the userID and institutionID does not exist in db as well, and I proved the hibernate as well. However, hibernate inserted the institution and trying to use insert to insert a new user. What is the difference here?